Question about modules from Atiyah-MacDonald 6.7.
In proposition 6.7 of Atiyah-MacDonald one proves that if a modules has a composition series of length $n$ than every other composition series has length $n$. To do this one proves that if $l(M)$ is the length of the shortest composition series of $M$  and $N\subset M$ is a submodule then $l(N)<l(M)$. Showing $\leq$ is easy by taking the intersection with $N$ of a composition series $M=M_0\supset M_1\supset M_2\supset\cdots$ of length $l(M)$; then $N\cap M_i=:N_i$ is a composition series of $N$ after removing terms where $N_i=N_{i+1}$. Saying that $l(M)=l(N)$ is to say that $N_i=N_{i+1}$ never happens or equivalently that $N_{i-1}/N_{i}\simeq M_{i-1}/M_{i}$ for all $i=0,\ldots, n-1$. Since $N_{n}=M_{n}=0$ this means that $N_{n-1}=M_{n-1}$ and in the book it is written "hence $N_{n-2}=M_{n-2}\ldots$ and finally  $M=N$". I am trying to prove this last assertion.
More generally suppose that $A\subseteq N\subseteq M$ are modules such that the inclusion $i:N\rightarrow M$ factors in the quotient by $A$ as an isomorphism $\varphi: N/A\rightarrow M/A$ then I want to show that $M=N$.
$\hspace{5cm}$
To do this I thought of considering the quotient module
$$
0=\frac{M/A}{N/A}\simeq M/N
$$
(to be perfectly clear one should say that we are actually considering the image of $N/A$ inside $M/A$ given by the isomorphism)  which means that $M=N$. Is this correct? Is there an easier way that Atiyah and MacDonald are not saying?

Yes, your reasoning is correct. You can also do in following way: we know $N_{n-2}\subseteq M_{n-2}$. Let $x\in M_{n-2}$. Then, given $M_{n-1}=N_{n-1}$,
$$x+N_{n-1}\in M_{n-2}/N_{n-1}= N_{n-2}/N_{n-1}.$$
So $\exists y\in N_{n-2}$ such that $x+N_{n-1}=y+N_{n-1}$. That is $x-y\in N_{n-1}$. Since $N_{n-2}\supseteq N_{n-1}$ and $y\in N_{n-2}$, we have $x\in N_{n-2}$. Thus $N_{n-2}=M_{n-2}$.

By the way, similar argument shows that $N_{n-2}\subseteq M_{n-2}$.
